# Блокировка доступа nginx при обращении не из iframe

Tags: nginx

Есть iframe-страница `site.ru/embed/12345` с плеером, которая предназначена для вставки плеера на другие сайты.

Как заблокировать доступ к этой странице на сайте, но разрешить, если страница вставлена в другие сайты?

Прописан `rewrite ^/embed/([0-9]+)$ /embed.php?v=$1 last;`

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, в чём состоят отличия этих двух состояний с точки зрения **абстрактного** http-сервера, а уж как это реализовать в конкретном (nginx), кто-нибудь подскажет. чтобы внести исправления в текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете права доступа сконфигурировать в [location](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

К примеру:

```
location /embed/([0-9]+)$ {
    deny 192.168.1.0/32;  # IP или подсеть, для которых хотим запретить доступ
    allow  all;  # разрешаем всем остальным
    rewrite ^/embed/([0-9]+)$ /embed.php?v=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: а как это затрагивает фреймы?

Comment: никак. nginx ограничить доступ может только по хедерам и мета-данным, парсить html он не может. Если у вас страница подгружается отдельно от основного документа, то все будет ок. Если же вы хотите удалить тег iframe из html - воспользуйтесь другими инструментами. Самый простой и неправильный это скопировать эту страницу без iframe и nginx'ом реврайтить на нее

Comment: *никак* — т.е., вы понимаете, что ваш «ответ» не является полноценным ответом на вопрос?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, согласен. поспешил с ответом. если будет уточнение вопроса - поправлю ответ. Если нет - удалю.

Answer (score 0):

насколько я понимаю, определить, что html-код, обращающийся к вашему сайту, находится именно в *iframe*, вообще невозможно.

отчасти можно лишь рассчитывать на наличие [http-заголовка referer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), хотя подставить какой-нибудь при обращении даже без всяких *iframe-ов*, скорее всего, несложно.

манипуляции с этим заголовком многократно описаны в интернете (поисковый запрос: «nginx http_referer»). например, можно воспользоваться [модулем http_referer](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) или напрямую использовать переменную `$http_referer` ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917016/4827341)).